# How I can get the number of subsets of a category?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a category table for my products and called: TBL_Category

The table structure is as follows:

**nid** is identity key

| nid | pid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | mobile |
| 2 | 2 | tablet |
| 3 | 1 | apple |
| 4 | 1 | samsung |
| 5 | 3 | iphone 11 |
| 6 | 3 | iphone 12 |
| 7 | 4 | Galaxy S |
| 8 | 4 | Galaxy Note |
| 9 | 5 | 11 pro |
| 10 | 5 | 11 promax |
| 11 | 6 | 12 pro |
| 12 | 6 | 12 promax |
| 13 | 7 | Galaxy S10 |
| 14 | 7 | Galaxy S10 Lite |
| 15 | 8 | Galaxy Note 10 |
| 16 | 8 | Galaxy Note 10 Pro |

Now how do I get the number one category?

**For example:**

when the user selects the number of Apple subsets to be displayed: 6

Or if it chooses to display mobile subsets: 14 records

Or if it selects the Galaxy Note, it should be displayed: 2

I mean, I want the number of all subsets

**thanks**

Comment: You must use the Group By function.

Comment: And you might want `having` and `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your guidance, I got it in the following way:

```
with cte as (
    select nid
    from TB_Category
    where nid = 429
    union all
    select ca.nid
    from cte ct
    inner join TB_Category ca on ca.parentid = ct.nid
)
select p.nid
from TB_Category p
inner join cte ct on ct.nid = p.nid
```

Comment: The join in your outer query is superfluous.